# How to resolve - TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

```
Temp_ = [274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523]

import math as mt
Debye_A = 3.3690e-01 - 6.3210e-04*Temp_ + (9.1425/Temp_) - (1.3514e-02*mt.log(Temp_)) + (2.2609e-03/(Temp_-263)) + (1.9212e-06*(Temp_**2)) + (45.2586/(680-Temp_))
```

I tried to do this and I get this error, how do I g

Comment: You first need to figure out exactly where the problem happens. The error message should point to the exact multiplication that causes the error. Otherwise, you can break up the long expression into smaller parts to issolate where the error occurs.

Comment: Are you expecting `Temp_` to be a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform mathematical operations on every element of an array, you should use numpy.  If you want to do it in a regular Python list, you have to loop or use an explicit mapping / comprehension on the list elements:

```
import math as mt

def f(t):
    return 3.3690e-01 - 6.3210e-04*t + (9.1425/t) - (1.3514e-02*mt.log(t)) \
         + (2.2609e-03/(t-263)) + (1.9212e-06*(t**2)) + (45.2586/(680-t))

Debye_A = [ f(t) for t in Temp_ ]

# or 

Debye_A = list(map(f,Temp_))

print(Debye_A)
[0.37713150689152897, 0.3776416978945515, 0.3781607869090762,
 0.37868820860326485, 0.37922354847328565, ...
```

Comment: This was insightful, I was able to get different approaches to solve this, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy` to convert `Temp_` list as a numpy array and replace `math.log` by `np.log`

```
import numpy as np

Temp_ = np.array(Temp_)

Debye_A = 3.3690e-01 - 6.3210e-04*Temp_ + (9.1425/Temp_) - (1.3514e-02*np.log(Temp_)) \
          + (2.2609e-03/(Temp_-263)) + (1.9212e-06*(Temp_**2)) + (45.2586/(680-Temp_))
```

Output:

```
>>> Debye_A
array([0.37713151, 0.3776417 , 0.37816079, 0.37868821, 0.37922355,
       0.3797665 , 0.38031681, 0.38087432, 0.38143886, 0.38201033,
       0.38258863, 0.38317368, 0.38376543, 0.38436382, 0.3849688 ,
       0.38558036, 0.38619844, 0.38682303, 0.38745412, 0.38809167,
       0.38873568, 0.38938613, 0.39004302, 0.39070633, 0.39137606,
       0.39205221, 0.39273477, 0.39342374, 0.39411911, 0.39482089,
       0.39552908, 0.39624368, 0.39696468, 0.3976921 , 0.39842594,
       0.39916619, 0.39991286, 0.40066596, 0.4014255 , 0.40219147,
       0.40296389, 0.40374276, 0.40452808, 0.40531987, 0.40611813,
       0.40692287, 0.4077341 , 0.40855183, 0.40937606, 0.41020681,
       0.41104408, 0.41188789, 0.41273824, 0.41359515, 0.41445862,
       0.41532867, 0.41620532, 0.41708856, 0.41797842, 0.4188749 ,
       0.41977803, 0.4206878 , 0.42160425, 0.42252737, 0.42345718,
       0.4243937 , 0.42533695, 0.42628693, 0.42724366, 0.42820717,
       0.42917745, 0.43015454, 0.43113845, 0.43212919, 0.43312678,
       0.43413123, 0.43514258, 0.43616083, 0.437186  , 0.43821812,
       0.4392572 , 0.44030326, 0.44135632, 0.4424164 , 0.44348352,
       0.44455771, 0.44563898, 0.44672735, 0.44782286, 0.44892551,
       0.45003534, 0.45115236, 0.45227661, 0.4534081 , 0.45454685,
       0.4556929 , 0.45684627, 0.45800699, 0.45917507, 0.46035055,
       0.46153346, 0.46272381, 0.46392164, 0.46512699, 0.46633986,
       0.4675603 , 0.46878834, 0.470024  , 0.47126732, 0.47251832,
       0.47377704, 0.47504351, 0.47631776, 0.47759983, 0.47888974,
       0.48018754, 0.48149326, 0.48280693, 0.48412859, 0.48545828,
       0.48679602, 0.48814187, 0.48949586, 0.49085802, 0.49222839,
       0.49360703, 0.49499396, 0.49638923, 0.49779287, 0.49920494,
       0.50062548, 0.50205452, 0.50349212, 0.50493832, 0.50639316,
       0.5078567 , 0.50932898, 0.51081004, 0.51229994, 0.51379873,
       0.51530646, 0.51682318, 0.51834894, 0.51988379, 0.5214278 ,
       0.52298101, 0.52454347, 0.52611526, 0.52769642, 0.52928701,
       0.5308871 , 0.53249674, 0.534116  , 0.53574494, 0.53738361,
       0.5390321 , 0.54069045, 0.54235875, 0.54403705, 0.54572543,
       0.54742396, 0.54913271, 0.55085175, 0.55258115, 0.554321  ,
       0.55607137, 0.55783233, 0.55960397, 0.56138636, 0.56317959,
       0.56498375, 0.56679891, 0.56862516, 0.5704626 , 0.57231131,
       0.57417138, 0.57604291, 0.57792598, 0.57982071, 0.58172718,
       0.58364549, 0.58557575, 0.58751805, 0.58947252, 0.59143924,
       0.59341833, 0.59540991, 0.59741408, 0.59943097, 0.60146068,
       0.60350334, 0.60555908, 0.607628  , 0.60971025, 0.61180596,
       0.61391524, 0.61603824, 0.6181751 , 0.62032595, 0.62249094,
       0.62467021, 0.62686391, 0.62907218, 0.6312952 , 0.6335331 ,
       0.63578606, 0.63805423, 0.64033778, 0.64263689, 0.64495172,
       0.64728245, 0.64962927, 0.65199235, 0.65437189, 0.65676808,
       0.65918112, 0.66161121, 0.66405854, 0.66652334, 0.66900581,
       0.67150618, 0.67402466, 0.67656149, 0.67911689, 0.68169112,
       0.6842844 , 0.68689699, 0.68952915, 0.69218113, 0.69485321,
       0.69754564, 0.70025872, 0.70299273, 0.70574796, 0.7085247 ,
       0.71132327, 0.71414398, 0.71698714, 0.71985309, 0.72274216,
       0.72565469, 0.72859104, 0.73155157, 0.73453665, 0.73754666,
       0.74058198, 0.74364302, 0.74673017, 0.74984387, 0.75298454])
```

Comment: @Ayodeji001. Is it what you expect?

Comment: This worked out so fine, gracias

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get around this by converting the list to an array:

```
Temp_ = np.array(Temp_)
```

Then I tried running it again, and this error was found:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
> Here is the full solution:
> Temp_ = np.array(Temp_)

Debye_A = 3.3690e-01 - 6.3210e-04*Temp_ + (9.1425/Temp_) - (1.3514e-02*np.log(Temp_)) + (2.2609e-03/(Temp_-263)) + (1.9212e-06*(Temp_**2)) + (45.2586/(680-Temp_))

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is this a solution? It starts off with one, but given the error it sounds like this isn't a full solution? Can you clarify?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Done that, thank you.